# Arranging div in different orders

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve stacking of divs in different order as shown in the image. Tried in flex but ended up in vain. [image]

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
</ul>
ul{
  background:#b9b3af;
  padding:30px 20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
  height:200px
}
li{
  background:#fff;
  padding:40px;
  text-align:center;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:10px
}
```

Also refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwLovwxe/)

Comment: Checked my answer given below.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cwLovwxe/1/)**

```css
ul{
  background:#b9b3af;
  padding:30px 20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
  height:250px
}
li{
  background:#fff;
  padding:40px;
  text-align:center;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
 <li>8</li>
 <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly he wanted number 2 to be below number 1 and so on .. ?

Comment: @trainoasis Updated the answer

Comment: Height does the trick right. Some how i missed it. Thanks dude

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Yeah you should provide hieght for the children to occupy :)